# For an odd integer $n$ with only two distinct prime factors, sum of its positive divisors always less than $2n$.

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove that for an odd integer $n$ with only two distinct prime factors, $\sigma(n) < 2n$. I used the multiplicative property of sigma function but didn't get much progress. Any insights will be appreciated!

Comment: Explicitly: you need to show that $1+p+q+pq<2pq$, $2$ cases: a) $p$ or $q$ $=2$, b) $p,q\ge3$ obvious as $1+p+q<\frac{pq}{3}+\frac{pq}{3}+\frac{pq}{3}$. Unless it's meant $n=p^\alpha q^\beta$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n = p^\alpha q^\beta$ where $p<q$ are distinct odd primes.
$$\sigma(p^\alpha) = p^\alpha + p^{\alpha-1} + \ldots + 1 = \frac{p^{\alpha+1}-1}{p-1} < p^\alpha \frac{p}{p-1}$$
and similarly for $q$.
Since $p \ge 3$ and $q \ge 5$, $\sigma(p^\alpha) < \frac{3}{2} p^\alpha$ and $\sigma(q^\beta) < \frac{5}{4} q^\beta$, and then
$$\sigma(n) = \sigma(p^\alpha) \sigma(q^\beta) < \frac{15}{8} p^\alpha q^\beta = \frac{15}{8} n $$
which is slightly better than what you need, as $15/8 < 2$.

Comment: How did you find those bounds? Trial and error?

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you so much^